# How to serialize any dart object into json?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, in-app-purchase

I want to serialize any object into a json string.

For example the PurchaseDetails object I receive after a successful purchase.

It has the following structure:

```
/// Represents the transaction details of a purchase.
class PurchaseDetails {
  PurchaseDetails({
    this.purchaseID,
    required this.productID,
    required this.verificationData,
    required this.transactionDate,
    required this.status,
  });

  final String? purchaseID;

  final String productID;

  final PurchaseVerificationData verificationData;

  final String? transactionDate;

  PurchaseStatus status;

  IAPError? error;

  bool pendingCompletePurchase = false;
}
```

Our Back End have requested this output as a JSON and I just need a quick way to parse it.

Is there such a way, and if not, what is best practice when serializing classes from a third party library?

Comment: I really just need to do this once when debugging and hitting a break point, but I cant copy the value as a Json from the `variables` tab in the `Debug` section.
It would be better if I could do it programmatically though since it could be useful in many scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write custom function which returns string which can be serialized in json like:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var c = MyClass();

  print(jsonDecode(c.toString())); // <- here is your json
}

class MyClass {
  String name = "Mark";
  int age = 25;

   @override
  String toString() {
    return '{"name": "$name", "age": "$age"}';
  }
}
```

EDIT:
You can also use this if you want to check other objects:
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-getting-list-of-fields-and-methods-in-a-class

Comment: This only works with classes I create.
I want to be able to represent any object as a JSON.

If for example I have a Theme object I want to print it as a JSON field. If you use the debugger it already show the tree structure a JSON string would have. I just have to get that into code.

Comment: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-getting-list-of-fields-and-methods-in-a-class

Here is your answer :]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Json Serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), which is a dart package which uses meta-programming to build and handle the serialization code behind the scenes.

You can define which properties to save, which keys to use, and  you can also provide custom conversion callbacks and decide whether to serialize null values and much more.

Comment: We are using it to generate serializable objects for our own models, but how would you use it on classes from other packages?

Comment: Do you mean serializing a complex object from another object as a field in your subclass or serializing the object by itself as if it were created by you?

Comment: When you inspect an Object at a break point in debug mode you see the object. Then you can expand it, showing its properties.
If one of those properties are a non primitive class like a list or another object you can expand that property too. You can keep doing this until everything is expanded. Now, I want to convert this into a json so that each property becomes a Map entry with its name as the key and the value as the value. Does that make sense?